# Ensure a service is _not_ started at boot, even if it was running on shutdown

Tags: systemd

Using `systemd`, how can I configure a service *not* to start at boot, even if it was running when I most recently shut down? I know that I can *disable* a service, but if I *start* that service, then reboot, it will continue to run. I want this:

1. Start the service now.
2. Reboot.
3. Service is *not* active/running.

I searched the web for an answer, but I found too much noise from people asking and answering about starting/stopping and enabling/disabling services in general. From what I can tell, I suppose I want to explicitly disable the service at boot time. I'm an Advanced Beginner with Linux. Where would I put this instruction to ensure that it happens at the appropriate point in the boot sequence?

Or is there another sensible and reliable way to do this?

UPDATE: I decided, in the end, that I shouldn't install this as a service at all. This seems obvious, looking back.

Comment: How do you start the service? Starting a service shouldn’t enable it...

Comment: @StephenKitt I started it with `systemctl start`. I was surprised, too, when it ran on reboot. `systemctl list-unit-files` lists the service as disabled.

Comment: It would be nice to motivate your question. What is the actual case where you want to do this?

Comment: Could you give the linux distribution and the service name showing this behaviour? Also some services have "socket activation", perhaps that's what happened (eg on Debian, there's ssh.service and also ssh.socket, you can disable the former and enable the later)

Comment: anyway,  that's probably this, but since I'm not well versed in systemd, I'd rather not do an answer: [systemd: Masking units](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-masking-units/) (If it works, post it yourself as answer please).

Answer (score 1):

The `foo` service starting program (which *you* need to *improve*) could be something testing the presence of a given file, e.g. `/var/tmp/dont_start_foo_service`, and if that file is present don't do anything more so `exit` immediately.

In your C code, use [access(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) to test the existence of a file.

In your shell scripts, use [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) for that, e.g. `[ -f /var/tmp/dont_start_foo_service ];`

See also [hier(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) for file name conventions, and `/etc/nologin` documented in [nologin(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nologin.5.html) as prior art.

To create (before previous shutdown or reboot) that `/var/tmp/dont_start_foo_service` you could use [touch(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html) (or [creat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/creat.2.html) in C code).

You would forcibly and explicitly remove (e.g. with [rm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html) or [remove(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/remove.3.html) ...) that `/var/tmp/dont_start_foo_service`  before `systemctl start` to really start `foo`.

You could even want to use some [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) database or [JSON](https://json.org/) file instead of that `/var/tmp/dont_start_foo_service` which would somehow store your *dontstart* flag.

Consider also [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) jobs with `@reboot` time specifications, or `at` or `batch` jobs (see [this](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm)).

Comment: None of this seems to relate to systemd, so I'm confused. I want the equivalent of "stop this service whenever I boot".

Comment: That "stop this service whenever I boot" is *exactly* `touch /var/tmp/dont_start_foo_service` and of course you need to configure your `foo` service per the hints given above

Comment: I want to be able to start the service using `systemctl start`. If I change the start script/command, that would prevent me from starting the service _at all_ using `systemctl start`, would it not?

Comment: No, your starting script will test existence of `/var/tmp/dont_start_foo_service`and exit prematurely if that file exists

Comment: So I am supposed to remember to create that file before I shut down my machine, but remove that file when I want to start the service? My goal is to _always_ _stop_ (not merely never start) the service at boot, but otherwise be able to start and stop the service on demand.

Comment: I suppose I'm left to conclude that I simply shouldn't install this as a service at all.

Comment: No, you install it as a service, but you also code additional logic to terminate the startup prematurely